# May I ask why my answer was deleted?

Tags: discussion

I posted my answer two days ago, in an area I have extensive knowledge in and ended up writing my own library after ravaging SO and finding nothing.

Isn't this part of SO's mantra: if you can't find a good solution, make your own and report back to the community?

[Drag drop functionality on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975712/drag-drop-functionality-on-ipad)

Comment: This is not the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You should post this on Meta really...

Comment: perhaps it was migrated to another site ?

Comment: +1 for the courage you have shown ;) let me tell you the trick you can ask question which has been already asked but the answers are not good, so just state that explicitly while writing your question.

Comment: Perhaps your answer was deleted because it had a *"I work at www.WorkSite.com"* line.

Comment: @Brogrammer - FYI, posting a duplicate question is highly frowned upon. Either edit the existing one to make it better in hopes of actually getting good answers, or add a bounty.

Comment: You speak of this mantra of SO, yet you asked about SO on SO.  I don't think your understanding of our mantras is any good.

Comment: Fair enough. FWIW, I was not trying to shamelessly self-promote by claiming I work where I work. The reason I indicated where I work was more in the light of, 'see this library is being used in production', In fact, most here have no idea I've created a library for this very instance. I've tried jQuery UI/touch-punch as well as all of the others suggestions. Trust me, if they were the best solution (obviously subjective), then I would have up-voted those answers. Answer me this: in real life, if 4 people ask essentially the same question, would you not give the exact same answer each time?

Comment: @cdeszaq, Well well, How you are going to edit existing one if you don't own one, and the second thing is if you have rights to edit still the question could be way to older and it won't show it on recent feed. The thing about us is we never care to check more then first two page while looking for potential question to answer and sometimes as an OP you need answer straight away rather just wait for the old question to be found by someone. Instead stackoverflow should add feature in which if user found old question which hasn't been asked correctly then we should be able to flag it as NONSENSE!

Comment: @Bro - In fact, _anyone_ can suggest an edit to _almost any_ post. And even better is the fact that questions with edited posts (either the question or any of it's answers) are put back into the recent feed as if they were just asked. Adding a bounty to a question is also a _very_ good way of getting answers. Also, poor questions _can_ be flagged. Lastly, if you _need_ an answer right away, perhaps you should not be reliant on a _free_ service like Stack Overflow but instead should pay better programmers who better know what they are doing.

Answer (score 27):

You had four posts that were duplicates (in two pairs) where you were promoting your library.  In two of them you didn't disclose your affiliation as per the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

In addition to not disclosing your affiliation, you shouldn't just copy/paste links to your library on any post where it seems relevant.  If those posts are duplicates they should be closed as such.  If they're not, you should take the time to explain how your library solves the specific problem stated in each individual question.

Finally, concerning this:

> Isn't this part of SO's mantra: if you can't find a good solution, make your own and report back to the community?

In all of the cases where you posted a link to your library, there were existing answers that had been there for months.  This isn't a case of "can't find a good solution."  It seems rather like you just wanted to promote your library.  (Which is fine, but stay within the guidelines outlined in the FAQ.)

Comment: Again, I honestly was not trying to promote my library. To me, it just felt like the best answer. I am accepting your answer as it does make sense.